# Springboot and Lombok

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, lombok

I'm using Springboot and MySQL in order to make an API,
I'm currently facing a problem, and I cannot find any answers on the internet :

The problem is in my association Table "EtapeRecette.java" below i try to initialize the getters and setters with Lombok, but when i use @Data, i get no errors but when I findAll() with the RecetteRepository, i get an array of "etapes" empty, but if I set the getters and setters in "EtapeRecette.java" manually it works all good, same if i use @Getters and @Setters, is there any reasons @Data doesnt work?

I got 3 tables :

Recette.java

```
package org.microferme.charme.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="Recette")
public class Recette {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "nom")
    private String nom;

    @Column(name = "nb_personne")
    private int nbPersonne;

    @Column(name = "prix_par_personne")
    private float prixParPersonne;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recette", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("recette")
    private Set<MediaRecette> medias;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recette", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("recette")
    private Set<StockUtile> ingredients;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recette", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("recette")
    private Set<EtapeRecette> etapes;

    public Recette(String nom, int nbPersonne, float prixParPersonne) {
        //Si l'id n'est pas spécifié on prend la timestamp actuelle
        Date date = new Date();
        this.id = String.valueOf(new Timestamp(date.getTime()).getTime());

        this.nom = nom;
        this.nbPersonne = nbPersonne;
        this.prixParPersonne = prixParPersonne;
    }

    public void addMedia(MediaRecette media) {
        this.medias.add(media);
    }

    public void addIngredient(StockUtile ingredient) {
        this.ingredients.add(ingredient);
    }

    public void addEtape(EtapeRecette etapeRecette) {
        this.etapes.add(etapeRecette);
    }

}
```

Etape.java

```
package org.microferme.charme.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Etape")
public class Etape {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "ordre")
    private float ordre;

    @Column(name = "duree")
    private float duree;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    private Ustensile ustensile;

    public Etape() {
    }

    public Etape(float ordre, float duree, String description, Ustensile ustensile) {
        this.ordre = ordre;
        this.duree = duree;
        this.description = description;
        this.ustensile = ustensile;
    }
}
```

EtapeRecette which is an association table between Recette and Etape in order to have a many to many relationship

```
package org.microferme.charme.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.microferme.charme.model.embeddable.EtapeRecetteId;


@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "EtapeRecette")
public class EtapeRecette {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EtapeRecetteId id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapsId("recetteId")
    private Recette recette;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapsId("etapeId")
    private Etape etape;

    public EtapeRecette() {
    }

    public EtapeRecette(Recette recette, Etape etape) {
        this.id = new EtapeRecetteId(recette.getId(), etape.getId());
        this.recette = recette;
        this.etape = etape;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `@Data` generates not only `getters` and `setters` but also the `equals` and `hashCode` methods. The default implementation of these methods does not work well with Hibernate relationships like one-to-many and many-to-one. You are better of if you use a combination of `@Getter` `@Setter` and `@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)` and add `@EqualsAndHashCode.Include` to the ID field. Like this:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Table(name="Recette")
public class Recette {

    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recette", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("recette")
    private Set<EtapeRecette> etapes;
```

Based on: https://thorben-janssen.com/lombok-hibernate-how-to-avoid-common-pitfalls/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, will implement this ASAP ! :)

Answer (score 2):

#### `@Data` annotation

`@Data` annotation is equivalent to the combination of the following annotations:

- `@Getter`
- `@Setter`
- `@RequiredArgsConstructor`
- `@ToString`
- `@EqualsAndHashCode`

---

#### `@RequiredArgsConstructor` issue

All entities should have public no-arguments constructor. It's not generated by default when `@RequiredArgsConstructor` is used. To fix that when using `@Data` need to add `@NoArgsConstructor`

---

#### `@EqualsAndHashCode` issue

This annotation causing performance and memory consumption issues when fetching entities. In example using lazy `@OneToMany` mapping - when calling `hashCode()` all mapped entities would be fetched even it's lazy loading.

Also, it can cause issues with using entities in `HashSet` or `HashMap` when saving entity to database and id is generated on save. If entity object would be saved in hashSet and then saved - same entity will not be in hashSet. Because the hashes are different now.

---

#### `@ToString` issue

Similar issue as `@EqualsAndHashCode` with `@OneToMany` mapping. It can be used only when all lazy fields are excluded. You can add `@ToString.Exclude` on field or `@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)` on entity class.

---

#### Conclusion

Don't use `@Data` for entities, because it has combination of another lobok annotations that is cannot be used for entities. Exclude lazy fields when using `@ToString`. Always add `@NoArgsConstructor` if entity has builder or all-arguments constructor. Correct entity example:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Entity
@Table(name="Recette")
public class Recette { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, will take care of what you said and change this ASAP ! :)